# Getting incorect answer with sum function

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox

When I get the data from the datagridview into the following textboxes, and the function is applied on it, I usually get the incorrect result. I am applying the sum function and the answer it provides in the result.text is incorrect. 
Can someone kindly point out the problem in the following code?

```
public void addqty()
        {
            int a, b;
            bool isAValid = int.TryParse(val1.Text, out a);
            bool isBValid = int.TryParse(val2.Text, out b);
            result.Text = (a + b).ToString();
        }
```

Comment: the function looks fine, but what's val1 and val2? what the debugging tell you? and who calls the function?

Comment: Why not just try and debug it if you are using visual studio.

Comment: is there any other way instead of using boolean...??

Comment: Whats wrong with using a boolean? (and yes, that's the only way if you are using TryParse)

Comment: Looks like you never take into consideration whether or not A or B are valid when you add them and set them to result.Text. See Handicappedhero's Answer. That should be correct.

Answer (score 3):

If val1 or val2 fail the Parse, a or b will equal 0. You need to make sure they are valid numbers and handle it accordingly if not.

```
int a, b;
if (int.TryParse(val1.Text, out a) && int.TryParse(val2.Text, out b))
{
    result.Text = (a + b).ToString();
}
else
{
    //handle bad values
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not taking in account what to do if either A or B is NOT valid. Right now if A is valid and B is not, it will still return A. The same will be true for B. If this is not the functionality that you want, you may need to apply different code:

```
if (isAValid && isBValid) {result.Text = (a + b).ToString();}
```

Comment: is there any other way instead of using boolean...??

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking the results of `isAValid` and `isBValid`, so if either of them does not parse, the value of `a` and/or `b` will be `0`. You will still see a result, but it may well be wrong.

Comment: is there any other way instead of using boolean...??

Answer (score 1):

I have included simple validation for this function. You should always include null checks, parse checks etc... I suspect that either textbox 1 or 2 is sending some invalid data.

```
    public void addqty()
    {
        int a, b;
        if (!int.TryParse(val1.Text, out a) || int.TryParse(val2.Text, out b))
            result.Text = "Can't convert variable a or variable b";
        else
            result.Text = (a + b).ToString();                        
    }


        textBox1.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells["Serial #"].Value.ToString()) ? "0" : row.Cells["Serial #"].Value.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells["Barcode"].Value.ToString()) ? "0" : row.Cells["Barcode"].Value.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString()) ? "0" : row.Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString();
```